# Toggle theme mode using bloc in flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-theme, flutter-cubit

I'm new to flutter, I'm building an app using bloc for state management.
I'm trying to toggle theme mode using IconButton on the appBar but the theme won't change when I press the button.
how can I fix that ? I'm creating this app by watching a tutorial and I did everything like it except for the theme manager part as he had the theme data in the main.dart file I figured it'd be better to separate it.

**AppCubit**

```
class AppCubit extends Cubit<AppStates> {
  AppCubit() : super(NewsInitialState());

  static AppCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  bool isDark = false;

  void changeAppMode() {
    isDark = !isDark;
    emit(AppChangeModeState());
  }
}
```

**AppStates**

```
class AppChangeModeState extends AppStates {}
```

**ThemeManager**

```
class MyThemes {
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: HexColor('01000E'),
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleSpacing: 20,
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              statusBarColor: HexColor('01000E'),
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light),
          backgroundColor: HexColor('01000E'),
          elevation: 0,
          titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
        elevation: 20,
        backgroundColor: HexColor('01000E'),
      ),
      textTheme: const TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Colors.white,
      )));

  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
        titleSpacing: 20,
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.white,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      textTheme: const TextTheme(
        bodyText1: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBarTheme: const BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        elevation: 20,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ));
}
```

**HomeLayout**

```
class HomeLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeLayout> createState() => _HomeLayoutState();
}

class _HomeLayoutState extends State<HomeLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AppCubit()
        ..getBusiness()
        ..getSports()
        ..getScience(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text(
                'News App',
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    AppCubit.get(context).changeAppMode();
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.dark_mode),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: cubit.screens[cubit.currentIndex],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
              onTap: (index) {
                cubit.changeBottomNavBar(index);
              },
              items: cubit.bottomItems,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppCubit(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state) {},
        builder: (context, state) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
            themeMode:
                AppCubit.get(context).isDark ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
            home: const HomeLayout(),
          );
        },
      ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about Cubit, but I would try adding ```setState``` at first

Answer (score 0):

one of best practice and easiest way to store value for your appTheme is sharedpreferences. so it will be stored as long as the user not clean the installed app

you can put your getshredpref on initstate. or you can combine it with GetX as your controller.

package: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save value
await prefs.setBool('themeIsDark', true);

// get value
final bool? themeIsDark = prefs.getBool('themeIsDark');
```

Comment: i already use sharedpreferences but the main problem is that whenever i tap the button that's supposed to change the theme nothing happens to the UI

Comment: just called setstate every button clicked